# Find the equation of the sphere with points P such that the distance from P to A(−2, 4, 4) is twice the distance from P to B(6, 3, −1).

Tags: calculus, 3d, spheres, spherical-coordinates

As you can tell from the title, I need to find the equation of the sphere with points $P$ such that $2|PB| = |PA|$. The coordinates for $A$ are $(-2, 4, 4)$ and the coordinates for $B$ are $(6, 3, -1)$. I've been stuck on this for two hours and can't seem to figure it out. I got as far as
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - \frac{52}{3}x - \frac{16}{3}y+\frac{16}{3}z + \frac{148}{3} = 0$ but apparently this is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: If $P = (x,y,z)$, what are the distances $|PA|$ and $|PB|$ in terms of $x,y,z$?

Comment: |PA| would be 2|PB|

Comment: The coefficient before $x$ should be $-52/3$ [according to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4%28%28x-6%29%5E2%2B%28y-3%29%5E2%2B%28z%2B1%29%5E2%29+%3D+%28%28x%2B2%29%5E2+%2B+%28y-4%29%5E2%2B%28z-4%29%5E2%29).

Comment: You're right about that. I've gotten the center but that messes up what I had for my radius, also thank you for the help <3 :3

Answer (score 2):

Let an arbitrary point, P be (x,y,z). We have $A(-2,4,4)$ and $B(6, 3, -1)$ From the question, we know |PA| = 2|PB|.
Therefore,
$$ \sqrt{(x - (-2))^2 + (y-4)^2 + (z-4)^2} = 2\sqrt{(x - 6)^2 + (y-3)^2 + (z-(-1))^2}$$
$$(x +2)^2 + (y-4)^2 + (z-4)^2 = 4((x - 6)^2 + (y-3)^2 + (z+1)^2)$$
Using algebra,
$$x^2+4x+4+y^2-8y+16+z^2-8z+16= 4(x^2-12x+36+y^2-6y+9+z^2+2z+1)$$
$$x^2+4x+4+y^2-8y+16+z^2-8z+16= 4x^2-48x+144+4y^2-24y+36+4z^2+8z+4$$
$$-3x^2+52x-140-3y^2+16y-20-3z^2-16z+12=0$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2-(52/3)x-(16/3)y+(16/3)z+148/3=0$$ which is the form you were looking for. I am assuming there was some error somewhere in your calculations.

Comment: $+\frac {148}3$

Comment: The center is right but not the radius

Comment: Thanks. I made an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

We connect $A$ to $B$ and extend the line to the far side of the sphere.  The length $B$ to the far side of the sphere equals the length from $A$ to $B$ (putting this point twice as far from $A$ as it is from $B$).  Divide the distance from $A$ to $B$ in the required $2:1$ ratio. Producing this figure.

[image]

The center and radius of our sphere.

$r^2 = \|\frac 23 (A-B)\|^2 = \|\frac 23 (-8, 1, 5)\|^2 = \frac {4}{9} (8^2+1^2 + 5^2) = 40\\
C = B - \frac 13 (A-B) = (6,3,-1) - \frac 13 (-8,1,5) = (\frac {26}{3},\frac {8}{3},-\frac {8}{3})$

$(x - \frac {26}{3})^2 + (y-\frac {8}{3})^2 + (z+\frac {8}{3})^2 = 40$

Answer (score 0):

[Find the equation of the sphere with points P such that the distance from P to A(−2, 4, 4) is twice the distance from P to B(6, 3, −1).](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854672/find-the-equation-of-the-sphere-with-points-p-such-that-the-distance-from-p-to-a)

More generally,
in n dimensions
suppose that the distance from
P to A is
r times the distance from
P to B.

I will show:

If $r=1$ then
P
is the plane through
the midpoint of AB
perpendicular to
B-A.

If $r \ne 1$ then
P is a sphere
with center
$C
=\dfrac{r^2B-A}{r^2-1}
$
and radius
$\dfrac{r }{|r^2 - 1|}|B-A|
$.

(This is well known,
but I enjoyed working it out
and others might find this useful.)

The square of the distance
from P to A is
$r^2$
the distance from
P to B
so

$\sum_{k=1}^n (p_k-a_k)^2
=r^2\sum_{k=1}^n (p_k-b_k)^2
$
or
$\sum_{k=1}^n (p_k^2-2p_ka_k+a_k^2)
=r^2\sum_{k=1}^n (p_k^2-2p_kb_k+b_k^2)
$.

If $r=1$ then

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (2p_k(b_k-a_k)+a_k^2-b_k^2)\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^n (p_k(b_k-a_k)-\dfrac{b_k^2-a_k^2}{2})\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k(b_k-a_k)-\dfrac{(b_k-a_k)(b_k+a_k)}{2}\right)\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k(b_k-a_k)-\dfrac{b_k+a_k}{2}(b_k-a_k)\right)\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^n \left((p_k-\dfrac{b_k+a_k}{2})(b_k-a_k)\right)\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^n \left((p_k-c_k)(b_k-a_k)\right)
\qquad c_k=\dfrac{b_k+a_k}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

or,
in vector terms,
$(P-C)\cdot(B-A)
=0
$
where
$C=(A+B)/2
$
is the midpoint of
$AB$,
so P
is the plane through
the midpoint of AB
perpendicular to
B-A.

If $r^2\ne 1$
then

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left((r^2-1)p_k^2-2p_k(r^2b_k-a_k)+r^2b_k^2-a_k^2)\right)\\
&=(r^2-1)\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k^2-2p_k\dfrac{r^2b_k-a_k}{r^2-1}+\dfrac{r^2b_k^2-a_k^2}{r^2-1}\right)\\
&=(r^2-1)\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k^2-2p_kc_k+d_k\right)
\quad c_k=\dfrac{r^2b_k-a_k}{r^2-1},
d_k=\dfrac{r^2b_k^2-a_k^2}{r^2-1}\\
\text{so}\\
0
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k^2-2p_kc_k+d_k\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(p_k^2-2p_kc_k+c_k^2+d_k-c_k^2\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left((p_k^2-c_k)^2+d_k-c_k^2\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (p_k-c_k)^2-\sum_{k=1}^n(c_k^2-d_k)\\
\end{array}
$

Note that

$\begin{array}\\
c_k
&=\dfrac{r^2b_k-a_k}{r^2-1}\\
&=\dfrac{r^2}{r^2-1}b_k-\dfrac{1}{r^2-1}a_k\\
\end{array}
$

so that,
if
$C=(c_1, c_2, ..., c_n)$,
then
$C
=\dfrac{r^2}{r^2-1}B-\dfrac{1}{r^2-1}A
=\dfrac{r^2B-A}{r^2-1}
$.

Also,
since

$\begin{array}\\
c_k^2-d_k
&=\dfrac{(r^2b_k-a_k)^2}{(r^2-1)^2}-\dfrac{r^2b_k^2-a_k^2}{r^2-1}\\
&=\dfrac{(r^2b_k-a_k)^2-(r^2b_k^2-a_k^2)(r^2-1)}{(r^2-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{r^4b_k^2-2r^2b_ka_k+a_k^2-(r^4b_k^2-r^2b_k^2-r^2a_k^2+a_k^2)}{(r^2-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{-2r^2b_ka_k-(-r^2b_k^2-r^2a_k^2)}{(r^2-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{r^2(b_k^2-2b_ka_k+a_k^2)}{(r^2-1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{r^2 (b_k - a_k)^2}{(r^2 - 1)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n(c_k^2-d_k)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{r^2 (b_k - a_k)^2}{(r^2 - 1)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{r^2 }{(r^2 - 1)^2}\sum_{k=1}^n (b_k - a_k)^2\\
&=\dfrac{r^2 }{(r^2 - 1)^2}|B-A|^2\\
\end{array}
$

so the equation is

$\sum_{k=1}^n (p_k-c_k)^2
=\dfrac{r^2 }{(r^2 - 1)^2}|B-A|^2
$.

This is a sphere
with center
$C
=\dfrac{r^2B-A}{r^2-1}
$
and radius
$\dfrac{r }{|r^2 - 1|}|B-A|
$.